# Why do US Presidents take credit for legislations?

Tags: united-states, president, legislation

I have seen so often presidents take credit for major legislations. But other than cases like budget bills which originate from the president, presidents  just happen to be there and don't have a good justification or support to veto when a bill is passed. Shouldn't the legislature take most of the credit, especially when the president's party doesn't even control the congress?

Examples civil rights, national park etc

Comment: Do you have examples of a president claiming credit for *specific* legislation which they didn't originate?  I'll agree they often claim credit for trends, but I don't recall examples of them claiming specifics.

Comment: Most legislations on campaign finance, privacy and government accountability did not originate from the white house.

Comment: But did the White House claim credit for those?

Answer (score 8):

That is politicians for you. Note that much of the civil rights legislation was passed by the Republican Party over the objections of the Democrats. However, the Democrats insist on claiming credit for it.

As an example, "affirmative action" was actually created by President Nixon who first applied it to the building trades and then to racial quotas.

During the 2012 election cycle, in correcting a statement on the Democratic National Committee website that claimed the party has led the fight for civil rights for 200 years, the Washington Post noted:

> Certainly President Lyndon Johnson, a Texas Democrat, played an
>   essential role, but it is worth remembering that 80 percent of the
>   "no" votes in the Senate came from Democrats, including the late
>   Robert Byrd (W.Va.) and Albert Gore (Tenn.), father of the future vice
>   president. Republican votes, in fact, were essential in winning final
>   passage of the bill.
>
> Learn more:
>   http://www.naturalnews.com/041913_LA_Times_US_history_civil_rights_movement.html#ixzz46npFI3bU

Since the president is the one who signs a bill into law, he takes the opportunity to have the "photo op" and claim credit for it. If it fails or is regarded as bad by the people, then he will blame the other party and the congress.

"Heads I win, Tails you lose"

Comment: Do you have a source for Democrats claiming credit for civil rights legislation? The Democrats and Republicans sort of "swapped positions" in the latter half of the 20th century, and it is now Republicans trying to get rid of civil rights legislation while Democrats try to defend and strengthen it, but I've never heard a Democrat actually claim credit for the original civil rights legislation being passed.

Comment: @Era During the election campaigns of the past 40 years the Democrats have lied about their behavior from before the civil war up to the 70's or 80's. They range from having pretended to have supported Martin Luthor King Jr., pretending to take credit for the civil rights legislation that the Republicans passed while Johnson was President, hiding what Woodrow Wilson did, etc.

Comment: Can you provide evidence?

Comment: @Era Just from having lived through the campaigns and hearing what the Democrats claimed.

Comment: That's not evidence. I'm not saying you're wrong, but you need to be able to back up factual claims that you make. Personal experience isn't relevant.

Comment: Google is your friend. Just from a cursory search I found sites that actually give evidence. http://www.crisismagazine.com/2012/the-republicans-the-party-of-civil-rights http://www.naturalnews.com/041913_LA_Times_US_history_civil_rights_movement.html http://freedomoutpost.com/southern-manifesto-truth-democrats/

Comment: @sabbahillel - Personally, I think either party laying claim to events from more than ~20 years ago is facetious.  The current Republican party is not the Republicans of Lincoln's time.  The current Democrat party is not the Democrats of FDR.  Southern Democrats in what are now Republican states may have signed the Southern Manifesto, but LBJ (also a Democrat) forced through the Civil Rights Act and Voting Rights Act that countered it.  And all of that was long enough ago that the party composition of both parties has changed significantly since then.

Comment: @Bobson true. However, the point was that the Democrats have been consistent in their claims and have been lying consistently. In any case, this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Era - There's a HUGE difference between taking a stand against over-reaching of legislation and "trying to get rid of legislation". You seem to have an extreme lack of understanding of that concept with your claim.

Comment: @Dunk By "get rid of" I simply mean repeal. It's not the GOP platform, as far as I know (I should have been clearer on that) but there are individual Republicans who have libertarian tendencies and who support the repeal of specific pieces of civil rights legislation. Rand Paul is a prime example. I'm not trying to introduce any normative claims with any of my comments-- it's irrelevant whether *I personally* support the repeal of civil rights legislation. Please try to avoid being partisan and hyperdefensive on politics.SE.

Comment: BTW, none of the citations are valid. They are from biased sources and/or do not provide evidence for the claim in question: **Have Democrats claimed credit the civil rights legislation?** Note that one article is entitled "LA Times earns F in U.S. history by claiming Democrats led passage of civil rights legislation"; I'm not interested in what claims *LA Times* is making. This is really a simple empirical question and so far I haven't been shown a single piece of actual evidence, i.e. **a quote from a Democrat claiming that the Democratic Party was responsible for civil rights legislation**.

Answer (score 5):

The President is usually the figurehead of a Nation,  As the holder of the highest office, the President **is** the government in the mind of some people.  Because of this, the public as a whole associates anything that happens in that country with the President.

Since people already have a mental connection between the President and the good things that happen in the country, it is easy convince the public that the president deserves credit for those things.

It goes the other way too.  That same mental connection means that it is also easy to convince the public that the President deserves the blame for the bad things that happen, and since that is effective, people blame the President for things that happened too, regardless of whether or not the President was actually responsible for them.

Answer (score 0):

Those presidents take credit for laws are often **strong proponents for the bills that they sign into law.** (e.g. Obama for the Affordable Healthcare Act). Since, as mentioned earlier, the president is the **figurehead** for the nation (and its government).  Therefore, **the president's support (or lack of support) for a bill can profoundly impact how it is perceived by legislators and the people of the United States.**